# Similar but distinct match clauses

Tags: pattern-matching, rust

Let's say I have an `enum` with a few variants:

```
#[derive(Copy,Clone)]
enum Foo {
    Left(isize),
    Right(isize),
    Other,
    //...
}
```

And I want to pattern match on this, with very similar but not identical treatment of `Left` and `Right`.

I've ended up with:

```
match foo {
     Left(i) | Right(i) => {
          let i2 = match foo {
               Left(_) => -i,
               Right(_) => i,
               _  => unreachable!(),
          };
          move_sideways(i2);
          // non-trivial code, ie not a simple function call
     },
     Other => { ... }
}
```

Which isn't very satisfactory, and relies on not consuming `foo` the first time.  Is there a good idiom I'm missing to avoid re-matching or duplicating the rule?

Comment: I can't think of a better way to do it. However, take a look at your type: `Left(3)` and `Right(-3)` would encode exactly the same information, right? So your type is somewhat redundant. Maybe you could just replace `Left` and `Right` with `Sideways(isize)`. Sure, it doesn't solve what you're asking for, but *I* think the type should be redesigned... Or am I wrong?

Comment: That's just a shortcoming of my simplified example. The real type is nom::Input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to avoid duplicating the rule without having to modify the data structure. But if you want to avoid making `Foo` be a `Copy` type (leaving all else as is), here's a slight modification:

```
let foo = Left(34);
match foo {
    foo2 @ Left(_) | foo2 @ Right(_) => {
        let i = match foo2 {
            Left(i) => -i,
            Right(i) => i,
            _ => unreachable!(),
        };
        // ... non-trivial code
    }
    Other => (),
}
```

The value in `foo` will move to `foo2`.

(Perhaps it looks cleaner to use shadowing -- `foo` instead of `foo2`...)

Comment: I couldn't decide between the answers; picking this one because I'd forgotten about the @ syntax!

Answer (score 2):

I would probably go with the suggestion made by Lukas, but I tried to devise something anyway. It might help you if you can't change the way `Foo` is built.

I wouldn't say it is super-elegant, but an attempt was made:

```
use self::Foo::*;

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
enum Foo {
    Left(isize),
    Right(isize),
    Other,
    //...
}

impl From<Foo> for Option<isize> {
    fn from(foo: Foo) -> Option<isize> {
        match foo {
            Left(i) => Some(-i),
            Right(i) => Some(i),
            _ => None
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Left(4);

    if let Some(i) = <Option<isize>>::from(foo) {
        move_sideways(i);
    } else {
        match foo {
            Other => { },
            _ => unreachable!()
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first idea that comes to mind is to wrap your `enum` into `Option` instead of using the `Other` constructor:

```
enum Foo {
    Left(isize),
    Right(isize)
}

let foo = Some(Left(1));
let x = match foo {
    Some(y) => {
        let i2 = match y {
            Left(i) => -i,
            Right(i) => i
        };
        do_something(i2)
    },
    None => 0
};
```

If you do not want to do that, you could chain two `match`-expressions and use the first to handle the preprocessing of `Left` and `Right`:

```
let bar = Right(2);
let z = match match bar {
    Left(i) => Some(-i),
    Right(i) => Some(i),
    Other => None 
} {
    Some(i) => do_something(i),
    None => 0
};
```

If that does not help either because your case is even more complicated, I would just use one `match`-expression with separate cases for `Left`, `Right` and `Other` and move the common code into a function.